# how to enable particular radio button of radio group according to radio button id saved in shared preference in android studio

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I am developing Quiz App. In which there are two buttons for previous question and next question.What i want to do is when user selects answer from options (for options there are 4 radio buttons) and attempts next question but if the user wants to view previous question that time the same radio button should be enabled which ever previously selected by user. For that i used shared preferences for storing selected radio button id.
Here is my Code:
For next button click:

```
 nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int radioSelected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int userSelection = getSelectedAnswer(radioSelected);

            sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("Ans",userSelection);
            editor.commit();
            int correctAnswerForQuestion =firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();
            if(userSelection == correctAnswerForQuestion)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correct Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                currentQuizQuestion++;

                if(currentQuizQuestion>=quizCount)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"End of quiz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstQuestion=parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);
                    txtquestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
                    String[] possibleAnswers=firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");
                    uncheckedRadioButton();
                    optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);
                    optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
                    optionThree.setText(possibleAnswers[2]);
                    optionFour.setText(possibleAnswers[3]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You choose wrong answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                currentQuizQuestion++;
                firstQuestion=parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);
                txtquestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
                String[] possibleAnswers=firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");
               uncheckedRadioButton();
                optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);
                optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
                optionThree.setText(possibleAnswers[2]);
                optionFour.setText(possibleAnswers[3]);
            }
        }
    });
```

And for previous button:

```
previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            currentQuizQuestion--;
            if(currentQuizQuestion<0)
            {
                return;
            }
           checkedRadioButton();
            firstQuestion=parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);
            txtquestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
            String[] possibleAnswers=firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");
            optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);
            optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
            optionThree.setText(possibleAnswers[2]);
            optionFour.setText(possibleAnswers[3]);

        }
    });
    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

}
 private void checkedRadioButton() {
    int ans=1;
    int ans1=sharedPreferences.getInt("Ans",ans);



   if(optionOne.getId()==ans1)
   {

        optionOne.setChecked(true);


    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add tag to each radio button option optionOne.setTag("answer_tag", "one"). 
Store the selected tag, and compare radiobuttons.getTag("answer_tag) with the stored tag.